# VIM block indenting different

Tags: vim, comments

when I insert a comment on my mac I get the following:

```
/*
   Comment
   Comment
  */
```

but when I do it on my Linux machine I get the following:

```
/*
 * Comment
 * Comment
 */
```

What triggers this ? and how do I make my Mac machine be like on my Linux machine?

They are the same version.

UPDATE : `:set formatoptions:r worked`

Comment: `:help format-comments` and `:help 30.6`. You are probably looking for `m` flag.

Comment: do the two vims have same config?

Comment: They do have the same config. ryuichiro, i am new to vim, i ran those commands and there is nothing helpful in them. When running those commands, the comments are how they should be.

Comment: For this to work some flags must be present in 'formatoptions':

        r       insert the star when typing <Enter> in Insert mode


What does this mean?

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you.
:set formatoptions:r worked

Answer (score 0):

Some distribution/package install different global system vim options that could lead to different behavior.

To explore indentation settings :

- Read `:help indent.txt`
- then on each vim installation do a `:set` to see what options are actually set